# How to instantiate a generic list out of an unkown type?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have an object as a parameter and I want to make a generic list out of that object type. Most of times I want to send a custom object type. This code declares the concept of my problem.

```
public void myMethod(object myObject)
{
    List<typeof(myObject)> _NewList=new List<typeof(myObject)();
}
```

Comment: Do your classes have a common base class?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the method generic:

```
public void myMethod<T>(T myObject)
{
    List<T> _NewList = new List<T>();
}
```

You can constrain the type to an interface or base class if your method needs to execute anything consistent on these objects.

Answer (score 0):

Via reflection:

```
var type = myObject.GetType();
var genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type });

var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
```

But it would be better to use generics.