# List<T> from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a 3rd party library I am working with and have no access to change it. It has a property on one of its components that only accepts a `ThirdPartyList<T>(IList<T> items)`, but at the point I am about to set the property I have only an `IEnumerable`.

I can figure out what the type is going to be in my `IEnumerable` by looking at the first item and figuring it out with reflection and all the items in the `IEnumerable` will be of the same type, but the question is how do I turn that type into a new `ThirdPartyList<what do I put here>()`.

Thanks

CD

Comment: Also check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989054/instantiate-a-generic-class-using-reflection?lq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661382/how-to-instantiate-a-generic-list-out-of-an-unkown-type?lq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885453/creating-an-instance-of-generic-class-using-a-type-reflected-from-an-assembly?lq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154874/c-sharp-instantiate-a-list-given-a-reference-to-a-type?lq=1).

Comment: @AnthonyLambert You still have to convince the compiler that you do so in a way that's consistent (most importantly, type-compatible) with every other use of the generic structure. In fact, *that* is the point of generics; you can put everything in a `System.Collections.ArrayList` by casting it to `Object`.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert: The question is about *how* to put something particular *that the OP wants* there (in this case, the item type of the enumerable).

Answer (score -1):

Your element type , for example

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = GetProductList(); //Your code

ThirdPartyList<Product> customList = new ThirdPartyList<Product>(products);
```

Comment: The issue appears to be that `Product` is not known at the time the code is written.